# Opencart short seo url

Tags: php, url, opencart, url-routing

i have changed in the seo_url.php the folowing line.

```
from:
$url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];

to:
$url = '/' . $query->row['keyword'];
```

so if i click on a link on the website i always got the main url like

https://www.site.de/product

instead of 
https://www.site.de/category/subcategory/product

my problem is, that google has still the old url 
(https://www.site.de/category/subcategory/product)

if i type https://www.site.de/category/subcategory/product in the url i want it to change to https://www.site.de/product

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this https://websiteadvantage.com.au/HtAccess-301-Redirect-Generator tool to create the redirects with **301 Moved Permanently** all the URL you would like to change. Then add these redirects to your's site root `/.htaccess` file.

**Example**:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$  
RewriteRule ^category/subcategory/product$ /product? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Also you should submit a new `sitemap.xml` file to **Google Search Console** https://search.google.com/search-console/about.

Comment: Okay, that would work, but is there no other way by changing the source code?

Comment: Changing your source code has nothing to do with what **Google** has record. That is why you should also submit a new `sitemap.xml` file.

Comment: So I should remove all categories from the sitemap, to have only the pure product link?

Comment: No, you should generate a new `sitemap.xml` for products with the new URLs. You could also check the output of **Opencart** > **Extensions** > **Feeds** > **Google Sitemap** to see if the URLs of the products are what you want.